# How to start the same activity in landscape and in portrait mode?

Tags: java, android

I have a popup and I want to use it in two different activities. The problem is one activity is in landscape and another is in portrait mode. I know I could make two different popups for these activities but I wanted to know if there is a way to make the same layout start in landscape mode when I start it from landscape activity and also in portrait mode when I start it from portrait activity?

Answer (score 0):

Create a landscape and a portrait version of the xml for the layout.  Put the portrait in the layouts folder, and the landscape in layout-land.  Make them have the same name.  Then when you ask to inflate that layout it will automatically pick the correct orientation.